# Eager loading with Feathers JS 4 and Objection JS - Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: javascript, feathersjs, objection.js

I am using feathers js 4 with objection ORM and trying to create a service that returns objection js model data that includes an eager loaded BleongsToOneRelation but I keep getting the response:

**Cannot read property 'get' of undefined**

I have used the Feathers CLI to generate my service (and model) and then modified to add a relationship as follows:

**devices.model.js**

```
const { Model } = require('objection');

class devices extends Model {

  static get tableName() {
    return 'devices';
  }

  static get jsonSchema() {
    return {
      type: 'object',
      required: ['macAddress'],

      properties: {
        macAddress: { type: 'string' },
        circuitId: { type: 'integer' },
      }
    };
  }

  static get relationMappings() {

    const Circuit = require('./circuits.model')();
    const DeviceType = require('./device-types.model')();

    return {
      circuit: {
        relation: Model.BelongsToOneRelation,
        modelClass: Circuit,
        join: {
          from: 'devices.circuitId',
          to: 'circuits.id'
        }
      }
    };
  }

  $beforeInsert() {
    this.createdAt = this.updatedAt = new Date().toISOString();
  }

  $beforeUpdate() {
    this.updatedAt = new Date().toISOString();
  }
}

module.exports = function (app) {
  const db = app.get('knex');

  db.schema.hasTable('devices').then(exists => {
    if (!exists) {
      db.schema.createTable('devices', table => {
        table.increments('id');
        table.string('macAddress');
        table.integer('circuitId');
        table.timestamp('createdAt');
        table.timestamp('updatedAt');
      })
        .then(() => console.log('Created devices table')) // eslint-disable-line no-console
        .catch(e => console.error('Error creating devices table', e)); // eslint-disable-line no-console
    }
  })
    .catch(e => console.error('Error creating devices table', e)); // eslint-disable-line no-console

  return devices;
};
```

**device.class.js**

```
const { Devices } = require('./devices.class');
const createModel = require('../../models/devices.model');
const hooks = require('./devices.hooks');

module.exports = function (app) {
  const options = {
    Model: createModel(app),
    paginate: app.get('paginate'),
    whitelist: ['$eager', '$joinRelation', '$modifyEager'],
    allowedEager: ['circuit']
  };

  // Initialize our service with any options it requires
  app.use('/devices', new Devices(options, app));

  // Get our initialized service so that we can register hooks
  const service = app.service('devices');

  service.hooks(hooks);
};
```

Then I am calling the /devices GET request using *http://localhost:3030/devices?$eager=circuit*

and the result is:

```
{
    "name": "GeneralError",
    "message": "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined",
    "code": 500,
    "className": "general-error",
    "data": {},
    "errors": {}
}
```

Have tried adding a custom find() method to devices.class.js but this doesn't seem to help.

I've searched through similar questions here and read through the [feathers-objection docs](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-objection) but just can't see what I'm missing. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your `app` variable is undefined. Debugger could help you a lot if you add a breakpoint and check call stack to see why... Maybe you are not passing it everywhere correctly to your modules.

This is the code that throws your error:

https://runkit.com/embed/kipjj807i90l

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried running the debugger at the top of the service and app seems to always be defined, same at the top of the model. A little unsure about the runkit code you supplied, assume line 5 should be:

```a.get('knex')``` 

Do you know where this code is actually found so I can work backwards and find the issue?

Comment: In runkit code it  was just an example showing that if you try to call `<undefined var>.get(...)` function, the error that is thrown is exactly the same that you are getting from your API

Answer (score 0):

It happens because in your `relationMappings` you are initializing models without the `app` argument which is expected. In the [feathers-objection examples](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-objection#models) it is shown how to modify your models in order to use them in the relation mappings: you have to explicitly handle the missing `app` argument.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's much later, but I just found the same problem.

The solution is to modify the feathers-objection models with the following, based on the Models section [here](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-objection)

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  if (app) {
    const db = app.get('knex');
    .... etc
  }

  return User;
};

module.exports = User;
```